# How can I wait for every part to load before my game starts?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a game on **ROBLOX** which has parts that move.

When I join in my game, those parts have already disappeared because it's taken me to long to load in.

Is there  a way to wait for everything to load in before loading into the game?

I'm using this code so far, and no luck:

```
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
local part = Workspace:WaitForChild("Moving brick", "plane")
wait(part)
end)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you changed it so the connect happens when a character is added instead of the player everything should be loaded.

Comment: Use the player spawned Boolean at the beginning of the script

Comment: Did the parts already disappear, or have they not actually yet appeared? You say they already disappeared, but you also ask for a way to wait until they have loaded in.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar to this to wait until the player's character is in the workspace after they've first joined the game:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(player)
  repeat wait() until game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name)
  local part = Workspace:WaitForChild("Moving brick", "plane")
  wait(part)
end)
```

but I'm curious as to why your parts are disappearing in the first place.. Is this intended? Would it possibly be better if you were using another method to activate these parts (as opposed to waiting for a player to join)?

More context would be appreciated and would possibly lead to a better solution.